# Fluent Validation Conditional Rules

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluent, fluentvalidation

We have a conditional requirement that not empty rule should be applied to a field only when there is a flag turned on. Something like the code below.

Is this a correct approach?

```
public AccountSetupModelValidator(ISessionProvider sessionProvider)
    {
        var regexPatterns = new RegExPatterns();

        RuleFor(x => x.MemorableDate)
            .NotEmpty().WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_AccountSetup_1001_memorabledate);


        RuleFor(x => x.MemorableDateAnswer)
            .NotEmpty().WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_AccountSetup_1001_memorabledateanswer)
            .Matches(regexPatterns.MemorableDateFormat).WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_Onboarding_100007_memorabledateinvalidformat)
            .Length(5).WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_Onboarding_100006_maxlength);

       RuleFor(x => x.SecurityQuestion)
           .NotEmpty().WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_AccountSetup_1001_securityquestion);

        RuleFor(x => x.SecurityAnswer)
            .NotEmpty().WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_AccountSetup_1001_securityanswer) 
            .Length(1, 40).WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_Onboarding_100006_maxlength);

        if (sessionProvider.OnboardingApplicationData.ToggleNavigationView.HasProvisionalAccount)
        {

              RuleFor(x => x.TempCardNumber)
                .NotEmpty().WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_AccountSetup_100006_tempcard)
                .Matches(regexPatterns.NumericOnly)
                .WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_Onboarding_100007_numbersonly)
                .Length(15).WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_AccountSetup_100006_tempcard);

            RuleFor(x => x.SecurityCode)
                .NotEmpty().WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_AccountSetup_100006_tempcard)
                .Matches(regexPatterns.NumericOnly)
                .WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_Onboarding_100007_numbersonly)
                .Length(4).WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_AccountSetup_100006_securitycode);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend not trying to take a dependency on your sessionProvider, since that makes it much harder to test your validators independently.

Instead, make use of [FluentValidation's conditional When() and Unless()](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customising&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#WhenUnless) methods.

If your property HasProvisionalAccount is (or can be put) on the model class, you could rewrite the section like this:

```
// remove the if() statement, and use .When()
RuleFor(x => x.TempCardNumber)
    .NotEmpty().WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_AccountSetup_100006_tempcard)
    .Matches(regexPatterns.NumericOnly)
    .WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_Onboarding_100007_numbersonly)
    .Length(15).WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_AccountSetup_100006_tempcard)
    .When(x => x.HasProvisionalAccount);

RuleFor(x => x.SecurityCode)
    .NotEmpty().WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_AccountSetup_100006_tempcard)
    .Matches(regexPatterns.NumericOnly)
    .WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_Onboarding_100007_numbersonly)
    .Length(4).WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_AccountSetup_100006_securitycode)
    .When(x => x.HasProvisionalAccount);
```

Each rule will only execute when HasProvisionalAccount is true.